# excel vba lookup and multiple if function

Tags: vba

i have this code to copy data from one sheet to other based on multiple conditions

I have three sheets namely master,jan,feb. I want that value of cell B5 in sheet feb should be value of cell H7 in sheet master only if any of the cell of sheet feb in range I5:AM is non blank and value of cell an5 in sheet jan = "WRK." and so on look down up to row 81. And then lookup first emplty cell in range B5:B81 and select it If the date of any cell in range O:7:O100 in master sheet lies in current month of current year then copy cell b in parrallel to cell O and paste in first blank cell of sheet feb Range B:5B81.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRows()

Dim Cl As Range
Dim str As String
Dim RowUpdCrnt As Long
Dim LR As Long

Sheets("Feb").Range("B5:B81").Value = ""

LR = Cells(Sheets("Feb").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
RowUpdCrnt = 5

' In my test data, the "WRK."s are in column AN.  This For-Each only selects column AN.
' I assume all my "WRK."s are in a single column.  Replace "B" by the appropriate
' column letter for your data.


With Sheets("Jan")
  ' loop until last row with data in Column AN (and not the entire column) to save time
  For Each Cl In .Range("AN1:AN" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Cl.Value Like str And Sheets("Feb").Range(Cl.Address).Value <> "" Then
    'if the cell contains the correct value copy it to next empty row on sheet 2 &  delete the row
      If Not IsError(Application.Vlookup(.Range("B" & Cl.Row).Value, Sheets("Master").Range("H7:H200"), 1, 0)) Then   ' <-- verify the VLookup was successful
        Sheets("Feb").Range("B" & RowUpdCrnt).Value = Application.Vlookup(.Range("B" & Cl.Row).Value, Sheets("Master").Range("H7:H200"), 1, 0)
        RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
      End If  

      If Application.Worksheets("Feb").Range("I5:AK81") <> "" And Application.Worksheets("Jan").Range("I5:AM81") <> "TRF." Then
        Application.Worksheet("Feb").Range("B5:B81") = Application.Vlookup(Application.Worksheet("Jan").Range("B5"), Application.WorksheetFunction("Master").Range("H7:Q200"), 1, 0).Copy
        With Sheets("Feb").Range("B5").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
          Dim objDate As Date
          Dim ObjDate2 As Date
          'year, month, day
          objDate = DateSerial(1, 1, 2017)
          ObjDate2 = DateSerial(31, 1, 2017)
          If Application.Worksheets("master").Range("H7:H200").Value > ObjDate2 And Application.Worksheets("master").Range("H7:H200").Value < objDate Then      
            If Not IsError(Application.Vlookup(.Range("B" & Cl.Row).Value, Sheets("Master").Range("H7:H200"), 1, 0)) Then   ' <-- verify the VLookup was successful
              Sheets("Feb").Range("B" & RowUpdCrnt).Value = Application.Vlookup(.Range("B" & Cl.Row).Value, Sheets("Master").Range("H7:H200"), 1, 0)
              RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1
            End If
          End If
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
      End If
    End If
  Next Cl
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [copy data using vlookup and if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833275/copy-data-using-vlookup-and-if)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804530/vlookup-and-if-condition-copy-data-vba